# My MySQL ROOT user had no privileges, What caused it and what can I do?

Tags: mysql, root, privileges

I am logged into my ROOT account both command line and PMA and for some reason I have no privileges.

I had to flush the privileges because the install of an app required it. Now I try to create a database and denied. PMA says no privileges on create DB. But it seems to have removed even roots privileges

> GRANT SELECT ON . TO root@'localhost'; ERROR 1045 (28000): Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I don't know what caused it, I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far

Comment: I had to flush the privileges because the install of an app required it. Now I try to create a database and denied. PMA says no privileges on create DB. But it seems to have removed even roots privileges.

Comment: GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO root@'localhost';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how this happened but the best thing I thought of to do was to kill the mysqld, restart in safe mode. Export all my databases and purge MySQL package and re-install. Not the best solution but it worked.